# How to Update a incident/ticket in remedy via java api

Tags: remedy

What is the class used for updating the incident/ticket in remedy product via java api? can you give any example program for that? 
I have the entryID after raising the ticket, with the help, i need to update the same ticket/incident with different values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Standard ARS API - Entry class, you can create, modify or retrieve based on Entry ID.**

Below is snippet - to Modify an entry in a ARS form.

*// Modify the short description field on the specified entry.*

```
void modifyEntry(String entryId) {
try {
  Entry entry = server.getEntry(formName, entryId, null);
  entry.put(Constants.AR_CORE_SHORT_DESCRIPTION,new Value("Modified by JavaAPITest"));
  server.setEntry(formName, entryId, entry, null, 0);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Entry #" + entryId +" modified successfully.");
    }
 catch(ARException e) {
 ARExceptionHandler(e,"Cannot modify the entry. ");
 }
}
```

You can refer ***BMC Integration Doc 7.6 -Java API section*** for more detailed understanding which includes sample code illustrating how to use the Java API to create, modify, and query records in AR System.